# Is the Chi-square divergence a Bregman divergence?

Tags: convex-optimization, st.statistics

Is the Chi-squared divergence $\sum_{i} \frac{(x(i)-y(i))^2}{x(i)}$ a [Bregman divergence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence)? I.e., can it be written as
$\phi(x) - \phi(y) - \langle\phi'(y),x-y\rangle$?

If so, what is the potential function $\phi(x)$ from which it is generated?
If not, does there exists a Bregman divergence which bounds Chi-square divergence from above?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for Math, but still, why the downvote?

Comment: Not a proof, but since [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06148) introduces a generalization of Bregman divergences and then show this generalization includes the chi-squared divergence, it's fair to assume the "usual" Bregman divergences do not. As for the last question: KL divergence?

Comment: Thanks!
I it an interesting work.. however, I didn't spot there proof of non-existence (they indeed show their generalization includes the chi-squared, however, they don't show -- as far I understood -- it cannot be realized as a Bregman divergence).
+ I think that the Chi square upper bounds the KL and not vice-versa:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30693/an-upper-bound-for-chi-square-divergence-in-terms-of-kl-divergence-for-general-a

Comment: @Yonatan Of course, my bad :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\chi^2$-divergence is not a Bregman divergence.

I'll show it for sample size $n=1$. We would have
$$
(x-y)^2/x=f(x)-f(y)-f'(y)(x-y)$$
If $y=0$ and $x>0$ this says
$$x=f(x)-f(0)-xf'(0),$$
$$1=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x-f'(0).$$
Taking $x\to 0^+$ this gives the contradiction $1=0$.